# Apache/WAMP doesn't start anymore (moved from Serverfault)

Tags: windows-7, apache2, wamp

I can't make Apache/WAMP start after I removed a vhost, and it doesn't start after I restored the config. This is driving me nuts :)

Starting it from the command line doesn't give me anything.

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin>httpd.exe

C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin>
```

Tried debug mode:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin>httpd.exe -e debug
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module actions_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module alias_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module asis_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module auth_basic_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authn_default_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authn_file_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_default_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_groupfile_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_host_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module authz_user_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module autoindex_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module cgi_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module dir_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module env_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module include_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module isapi_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module log_config_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module mime_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module negotiation_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module rewrite_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module setenvif_module
[Fri Sep 13 13:26:23 2013] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module php5_module

C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin>
```

But if I try to start it from Services, it actually says it fails. From the Windows Event log:

```
The Apache2.2 service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function..
```

My first thought was that something (Skype) was using port 80, so I scanned open ports, but don't see it is being used:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin>netstat -ano | findstr 80
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1026           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       980
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4380         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3768
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1289      108.160.162.51:80      ESTABLISHED     3920
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1677      204.62.114.180:443     ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1678      204.62.114.180:443     ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1679      204.62.114.180:443     ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1680      204.62.114.180:443     ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1681      204.62.114.180:443     ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2125      38.123.7.203:80        ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2126      38.123.7.203:80        ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2127      38.123.7.203:80        ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2128      76.74.254.123:80       ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2131      173.194.32.45:80       ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2136      173.194.32.57:80       ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2137      173.194.32.38:80       ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2138      66.155.9.250:80        ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2141      173.194.32.57:80       ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2143      23.3.90.208:80         ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2144      173.241.240.153:80     TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2152      184.169.176.87:80      ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2161      107.21.38.221:80       ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2162      193.149.47.98:80       ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2166      66.155.9.250:80        ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2170      74.121.138.232:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2172      23.21.44.43:80         ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2173      173.192.220.64:80      ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2174      63.251.249.49:80       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2179      23.3.90.171:80         ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2180      23.3.91.115:80         ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2181      66.119.33.141:80       ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2182      63.251.249.50:80       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.1.18:2186      23.21.44.43:80         ESTABLISHED     4608
  TCP    [::]:1026              [::]:0                 LISTENING       980
  UDP    169.254.129.250:60880  *:*                                    4724
  UDP    [fe80::212e:6fdb:926d:bd2a%10]:546  *:*                                    980
  UDP    [fe80::212e:6fdb:926d:bd2a%10]:1900  *:*                                    4724
  UDP    [fe80::212e:6fdb:926d:bd2a%10]:60876  *:*                                    4724
  UDP    [fe80::8835:6af0:18df:81fa%22]:546  *:*                                    980
  UDP    [fe80::8835:6af0:18df:81fa%22]:1900  *:*                                    4724
  UDP    [fe80::8835:6af0:18df:81fa%22]:5353  *:*                                    1820
  UDP    [fe80::8835:6af0:18df:81fa%22]:60877  *:*                                    4724
```

Sorry for the super long question. Hope somebody knows what might be going on!

Comment: Also try `httpd.exe -t` and `httpd.exe -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` does that give you any clues?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No sorry, everything look OK by these commands. `Syntax OK`

Comment: Was there any more to that Event Log message?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sadly no.

Comment: Can you post the results of the `httpd.exe -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`